# Match property in two different arrays

Tags: swift

I am trying to match the property `flavour` in two different arrays.

Array one:

```
var myIcecreams = [
    Icecream(color: "yellow", flavour: "banana"),
    Icecream(color: "green", flavour: "mint"),
    Icecream(color: "white", flavour: "banana"),
    Icecream(color: "brown", flavour: "chocolate")
]
```

Array two:

```
var shopIcecreams = [
    Icecream(color: "red", flavour: "strawberry"),
    Icecream(color: "purple", flavour: "blueberry"),
    Icecream(color: "green", flavour: "pistachio"),
    Icecream(color: "white", flavour: "chocolate")
]
```

How can I make a new array, containing every element in `shopIcecreams` except the ones where the property `flavour` is matching each other, between the arrays? There is a match in the ice creams with `chocolate` as a flavour, which should be deleted in the new array.

I have tried this without any luck:

```
let filteredIcecreams = shopIcecreams.filter { newIcecream in
    myIcecreams.contains { myIcecream in
        newIcecream.flavour != myIcecream.flavour
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have zero clue.

Struct for Icecream:

```
struct Icecream: Encodable, Decodable {
    var color: String
    var flavour: String
}
```

Comment: This looks sort of like Swift... except it isn't valid Swift. And you mention trying to match a `uid` and then present code with no `uid`...

Comment: @jnpdx my mistake - edited with ```flavour```

Comment: Is `Icecream` a struct? Can you show the code? What is the custom `=>` operator, because it is not standard Swift. Also, you are using arrays, not dictionaries.

Comment: Yes, ```Icecream``` is a struct. Will add it now!

Comment: @GeoffHackworth I do not know what the correct operator is for arrays in swift, so I just wrote ```=>``` as I thought that was correct.

Comment: Downvoted because I can't understand what you're describing. Please post two examples of what the combination would entail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I think you want:

```
// All of the different flavours in myIcecreams as a Set to remove
// duplicates and increase performance of looking up flavours
// ["banana", "mint", "chocolate"]
let myFlavours = Set(myIcecreams.map { $0.flavour })

// All entries from `shopIcecreams` with a flavour not in `myFlavours`
let filteredIcecreams = shopIcecreams.filter { shopIcecream in
    !myFlavours.contains(shopIcecream.flavour)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
struct Icecream: Encodable, Decodable {
    var color: String
    var flavour: String
}


var myIcecreams = [
    Icecream(color: "yellow", flavour: "banana"),
    Icecream(color: "green", flavour: "mint"),
    Icecream(color: "white", flavour: "banana"),
    Icecream(color: "brown", flavour: "chocolate")
]

var shopIcecreams = [
    Icecream(color: "red", flavour: "strawberry"),
    Icecream(color: "purple", flavour: "blueberry"),
    Icecream(color: "green", flavour: "pistachio"),
    Icecream(color: "white", flavour: "chocolate")
]

var newArray: [Icecream] = []

for i in shopIcecreams {
    var match = false
    for j in myIcecreams {
        if i.flavour == j.flavour {
            match = true
            break
        }
        else {
            match = false
        }
    }
    if match == false {
        newArray.append(i)
    }
}

// Printing new array
for i in newArray {
    print(i)
}
```

[Click Here to see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8FpC.png)

### Output:

Icecream(color: "red", flavour: "strawberry")
Icecream(color: "purple", flavour: "blueberry")
Icecream(color: "green", flavour: "pistachio")